# Sign extending from a fixed bit width in Java/Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, bit-manipulation, twos-complement

I want to sign extend 12 bit numbers to 32 bits in Groovy (or Java, of course). I can find various recipes for this in C/C++ and so on, but not for Groovy/Java - could someone give me an algorithm or a code fragment?

Comment: Algorithm is a "recipe". The same algoritm that applies for C, can be applied for Java.

Comment: `(x << 20) >> 20` or `(x ^ 0x800) - 0x800`, whichever you like best/is more convenient. The first is easier to understand but it rarely gives further possibilities for simplification.

Comment: @harold, I can see how the second one works but not the first, unless those are arithmetic and not logical shifts

Comment: @adrianmcmenamin yes `>>` in Java is an arithmetic shift, the logical shift is `>>>`

Comment: @harold. Ah, and therein lies my basic problem. I didn't realise that (being a C programmer at heart) and that is why my original promotion code was not working. Would you like to post your comment as an answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to @harold:

```
 (x << 20) >> 20 or (x ^ 0x800) - 0x800, whichever you like best/is more   convenient. The first is easier to understand but it rarely gives further possibilities for simplification
```